# Please migrate Google Analytics questions to Webmasters

Tags: discussion, scope

Hello from [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com)!

We've been seeing an awful lot of questions about Google Analytics migrated from Super User over to Web Apps lately.

The thing is, questions about Google Analytics will be *much* better off over at [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) where they have over a thousand questions tagged [google-analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics).

While, yes, Google Analytics can be considered a Web App, by and large the questions are usually less about issues using the app and more about how to interpret/slice/read the data/reports, or otherwise use the app in a way that only webmasters care about, not the general public.

Rather than see such questions languish unanswered at Web Apps (or get closed) I'd rather see them at Webmasters where they can find experts who can answer them. Most Google apps are perfectly suited to Web Apps, but Google Analytics is a special case.

Comment: If I notice any, I'll make sure it goes the right way. If you have any wrongly migrated, and rejected, let us know, and we can see about kicking em over to the right site.

Answer (score 7):

Sadly, Pro Webmasters is not in our migration list:

[image]

Please note that last item on the list is only available to moderators (unless I missed an update). If a non-moderator could enlighten me on this point, I'd appreciate it ;)

So users would have to flag the question to have it moved by a moderator. This is probably the main reason why you're getting questions that are not an optimal fit for your site.

I don't know if it's possible to have an additional site on the list or if there is anything other to offer than the moderators keeping an eye on this kind of migration. Users close and migrate questions on their own though, and I really can't see anything we could do about that at the moment.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit unfortunate that Webmasters isn't in the set of default migration paths. Savvy Super Users will need to use the "other" option to suggest Webmasters as a target for migration. My hope with this post was to give a nudge to those non-Moderators.

Comment: If they're all tagged [google-analytics], we can have some people manually checking through the list, and flagging if we see new questions. Maybe add to the tag that it may be a better choice having it on Webmasters?

Comment: @CanadianLuke I think adjusting the tag summary is a great idea.

Comment: Step two... Finding out how to get people to read tag descriptions...

Comment: @JakeGould We might want to have a "feature request" question specifically for this, so that people can vote on it.